# Media query : "when width>2.5*height"

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I struggle with my responsive when my screen-width > 2.5*screen-height
I hate people who do that with their screen but they exist.

What would you do in my case ?
If you have strong documentation about the best practice for using media queries it could also be helpful. As a developper i'd like to spend as little time as possible to fight against every devices.

Thank's !!

Answer (score 0):

You do not state what you have tried so far and why it failed, but you can use `aspect-ratio` / `min-aspect-ratio` / `max-aspect-ratio`:

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 5/2) { 

}
```